# remove is not a function

Tags: javascript

```js
var selectedItems = [];
function selectItem(id) {
    selectedItems.push(id);
    console.log(selectedItems);
}
function unselectItem(id) {
    selectedItems.remove(id);
    console.log(selectedItems);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="selectItem(1);">select item 1</div>
<div onclick="selectItem(2);">select item 2</div>
<div onclick="selectItem(3);">select item 3</div>

<div onclick="unselectItem(1);">unselect item 1</div>
<div onclick="unselectItem(2);">unselect item 2</div>
<div onclick="unselectItem(3);">unselect item 3</div>
```

`selectedItems.remove is not a function"` в чем причина?

Comment: _в чем причина?_ - в том, что у массива нет функции remove. Откуда вообще взялось предположение, что она есть?

Comment: Не знаю как, но раньше это работало. Прям серьезно.

Comment: Очевидно раньше был другой код. Данный код не может работать в принципе. Если только не делать кровавый патч в Array.prototype, либо  _selectedItems_ был не массивом

Answer (score 0):

У массива нет метода `remove`, для удаления воспользуйтесь следующим способом:

```
function unselectItem(id) {
    var index = selectedItems.indexOf(id);
    if (index > -1) {
        selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log(selectedItems);
}
```

Comment: array is not defined

Comment: Замените на `selectedItems`, ответ поправил